# Condensing Data from 4 Columns to 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine two sets of columns down to one set in SQL, where all sets have a common JobID and Date.

I want to take columns FrOpr and BkOpr and condense them down to one Opr field while also take their corresponding FrExtract and BkExtract fields down to one corresponding Extract field.

[image: Before and After Picture]

Any thoughts on how to do this?

All the response are much appreciated. I adapted one of the queries below and used it to create a column of data that I wanted to reference and extract from in a larger query.

The output gives me two columns, an Opr and Extract column. In the larger query, I'm looking to select just values from the new Extract column and then Sum them up as a "Completed" output. My problem is knowing where/how to splice/nest this in to the existing query. Any thoughts on how to do this without creating a temp table? I'll post the larger query I want to add this to

SELECT CONCAT(Operators.OprExtID,'CIREG') AS Processor, Convert(VARCHAR(8), Data.StartDateTime, 112) AS [Processed Date], CONCAT('DEPTRI',Machines.EquipmentType,'',JobTypes.JobTypeDesc,'',Jobs.JobName) AS [Activity Type], SUM(Data.Handled) AS Completed FROM dbo.Operators, dbo.Data DataInput, dbo.jobs jobs, dbo.Machines, dbo.JobTypes WITH (nolock) WHERE (Jobs.ID = Data.JobID AND Data.FrOpr = Operators.Operator AND Data.MachNo = Machines.MachNo AND Data.JobTypeID = JobTypes.JobTypeID)

Processor   Processed Date  Activity Type   Completed 0023390_CIREG 20190116 DEPTRI_LWACS_EXTRACTION_UTGENERAL  43.61 0023390_CIREG 20190116    DEPTRI_MWACS_DOC PREP_AGGEN 7.76 0023390_CIREG  20190116    DEPTRI_SWACS_OPENING_UTGENERAL  808 –

Comment: All the response are much appreciated. I adapted one of the queries below and used it to create a column of data that I wanted to reference and extract from in a larger query.

Comment: put sample data and sample code in the question itself - not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT JobId , Date , FrOpr AS Opr , FrExtract AS Extract
FROM< TableName>
WHERE FrOpr IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT JobId , Date , BkOpr AS Opr , BkExtract AS Extract
FROM <TableName>
WHERE BkOpr IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Good and straight-forward answer. I'd use `UNION ALL` though. I see no reason why apply a `UNION [DISTINCT]` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this help!  I'm pretty green with SQL yet so this definitely helps.

Comment: @Amyers Np. You can accept this answer if this has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the future, please provide sample data and desired results in text form.

This is a pretty simple un-pivot, which I'd do with a Union:

```
Select 
    JobId
    , Date
    , FrOpr as Opr
    , FrExtract as Extract
    , 'Fr' as Source_Column_Set
From <table_name>
Where <whatever conditions your application requires>

Union

Select 
    JobId
    , Date
    , BkOpr as Opr
    , BkExtract as Extract
    , 'Bk' as Source_Column_Set
From <table_name>
Where <whatever conditions your application requires>
```

You can make that a CTE and sort the results any way you like.

p.s.  I included `Source_Column_Set` to avoid data loss.

Comment: The `Source_Column_Set` to show what a row represents is a good idea. It should be `UNION ALL` though, as there are no duplicates we want the DBMS to look for and get rid of. And there must be `FROM` clauses added of course. And `WHERE` clauses to omit null values.

Comment: Fair points, Thorsten, although a `Union` works here because the sample data provided has no duplicates.  I thought I'd added the `From` and `Where` clauses yesterday - I must have neglected to "save edits".

Comment: Yes, `UNION` works. Only, why give the DBMS additional work to do? Why have it look for duplicates when we know there are none?

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I had originally pasted in the table, but the preview of it didn't show the data aligning with the column headers correctly; I thought it would be confusing to paste in.  All this explanation has definitely helped, though!

Answer (score 1):

One option is a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Select A.JobID
      ,A.Date
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (FrOpr,FrExtract)
                     ,(BkOpr,BKExtract)
             ) B(Opr,Extract)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding with the Cross Apply option.  I didn't know this or Union existed as options.